# How to make this Longest Increasing Subsequence program return this subsequence

Tags: algorithm, subsequence

I have this code for Longest Increasing Subsequence. Right now it returns length of the longest increasing subsequence, but **I don't know how to make it return this exact subsequence**. For ex. in this case **it should return [3,6,7,8,9]**. Any ideas? I would appreciate not using very complicated syntax :D

```
a = [3, 6, 7, 2, 1, 8, 9, 5]
n = len(a)
q = [0] * n
for k in range(n):
    max = 0
    for j in range(k):
        if a[k] > a[j]:
            if q[j] > max:
                max = q[j]
    q[k] = max + 1
return(max(q))
```

outer loop iterates after all elements from a and inner loop checks if element k from table is greater than item from index 0 to k-1
Thanks to that q table for this example looks like this `[1,2,3,1,1,4,5,2]` We can see that `first element` makes `subsequence of length 1`, `second` one makes `subsequence of length 2` (with first element), `third element` makes `subsequence of length 3` (with first and second elements), `fourth element` makes `subsequence of length 1` because non of previous elements is smaller than it, and so on. So basically at each iteration it gets the length of the longest increasing subsequence ending at index k

Shorter version of the same program:

```
for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            if a[i] > a[j]:
                q[i] = max(q[i], 1 + q[j])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been great if you had described what your code was doing but as I understand at each iteration it gets the length of the longest increasing subsequence ending at index `k`.

To trace back the actual indices in the array, just add another array `previous[]`.

Initialize `previous = [-1] * n`.

And then

```
if q[j] > max: 
   max = q[j]
   previous[k] = j
```

Comment: This is not right, adding this results [-1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 2, 5, 0] in the outcome, not [3,6,7,8,9].

Comment: @lolos This is list of **indexes**, you need to rewind it in order 6-5-2-1-0 and reverse

Comment: @MBo It would be true if instead of last 0 was 6, so something is not right. It always fails for last element in subsequence

Comment: Or should I do something else, to get 6-5-2-1-0 order?

Comment: How from this I can find those elements?

Comment: @lolos From an index `i` you can construct the longest sequence ending at `i` by walking backwards.  So in the array for `i = 7` you see a `0` and at `0` you see `-1` so the longest rising sequence ending at position `7` has indexes `7, 0, -1` or in other words is `5, 3`.  Now just try each `i` until you find one of the right length...

Comment: We know that there is an answer of length 5, and it didn't end at index `7`.  So try index `6`.  We get the following list of indexes following the cookie trail.  `6, 5, 2, 1, 0, -1`.  That turns into the list `9, 8, 7, 6, 3` which has the right length so is the answer.  Unfortunately we got it constructed in reverse, so you need to reverse it to get your final answer of `3, 6, 7, 8, 9`.

Comment: @lolos You have to look for index of max value in q (instead of inbuilt  `max`) - here this index is 6, then walk from `previous[6]` to lower indexes of sequence.